# ArcGIS API for Python Delete Multiple Features

Tags: arcgis-python-api

Can you help me with my code below to delete/send multiple ObjectIDs to a delete parameter?

Currently the code just finds one record and send that Object ID to the delete paramter, but id like to be able to select a certain value in a attribute field and delete all or setup some sort of For or While Loop to pass all Object IDs to the delete paramter. One of the field names is 'Biologist' and a test record/value for the example is 'jah'.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from IPython.display import display

gis = GIS(username="xxx", password="xx")

search_result = gis.content.search('test url')
search_result[1]

test_item = search_result[1]
test_layers = test_item.layers
test_layers

test_fset = test_layers[0].query()
test_fset.df

test_flayer = test_layers[0]
test_flayer.properties.capabilities

test_features = test_fset.features

remove_feature = [f for f in test_features if f.attributes['Biologist'] == 'jah'][0]
dele = remove_feature.get_value('OBJECTID')

delete_result = test_flayer.edit_features(deletes=str(dele))
delete_result
```

Comment: create a feature layer, select layer by attribute (or use a where clause in your create feature layer) then use Delete_Features http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000036000000 **warning** deletion outside an edit session has no undo, be sure to have a backup.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I don't think the Delete_Features tool available in ArcGIS Pro/Map is supported in Hosted Feature Services/AGO data.

Comment: Ah, so it's not arcpy, your revision of tags has cleared that up. Does https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer (search for delete_features) help?

Answer (score 1):

The edit_features function expects a comma-separated list of object ids for the deletes argument.
See https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.delete_features for documentation.

The following should work:

```
remove_features = [f for f in test_features if f.attributes['Biologist'] == 'jah']
object_ids = [f.get_value('OBJECTID') for f in remove_features]
object_ids_str = ",".join(object_ids)
delete_result = test_flayer.edit_features(deletes=object_ids_str)
```